# Tobject memory address reservation/liberation

Tags: delphi

Say I have an instance to TMyobject

```
 MyObjectA := TMyObject.create
```

We can say that MyObjectA is an address in memory. Now if i do

```
 MyObjectA.free
```

Normally MyObjectA is still an adress in memory but the memory at that address is not reserved anymore, this why sometime doing MyObjectA.aProperty still work

Now If i do

```
 MyObjectB := TMyObject.create
```

What forbidd the system to gave to MyObjectB the address in memory that was previously used by MyObjectA ? and in this way is is possible that after doing MyObjectB := TMyObject.create that MyobjectA become valid ?

Comment: Variable `MyObjectA` is never an adress in memory but a reference/pointer to an adress in memory where the object itself is stored. When you call `MyObjectA.free` the object destructor is called. After the destuctor execution is finished the memory that was reseved for this object becomes available an can be reused by another object but the data in memory still remains. Trying to Access any properties of `MyObjectA` at this time is undefined and therefore unsafe so it shouldn't be done.

Comment: Odds are very high that the memory will be reused, given that the instance sizes are equal and fastmm is an aggressive (conservative if you will) memory manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing "forbids" the memory manager from immediately re-using the memory previously occupied by MyObjectA for MyObjectB.

There is no way (short of using a custom-designed memory manager) you can prevent it from (or force it to) doing that.

That doesn't mean, however, that MyObjectA suddenly becomes any more "valid" than it was before the allocation of MyObjectB. MyObjectA's *content* has been thoroughly overwritten by the *content* (instance) of MyObjectB, so even if the memory manager immediately reuses the memory previously occupied by MyObjectA for MyObjectB, it will not suddenly become any more "valid" than it was before. In essence, you can do the same with

```
MyObjectB := TMyObject.Create;
MyObjectA := MyObjectB;
```

ie. MyObjectA just becomes an alias to MyObjectB (if the memory is reused), but the original content of MyObjectA is lost forever in this case.

Comment: Assigning `MyOobjectB` to `MyObjectA` as shown in your examle doesn't mean that `MyObjectA` is lost forever. The data of `MyObjectA` still remains in memory there just isn't any reference to that data block any more provided that `MyOBjectA` variable was the only reference to that object. Therefore in ARC based application object that `MyObjectA` was referencing will be destroyed and memory freed as it reference count reached zero. But on non-ARC based application this leads to memory leaks since from memory manager point of view that part of memory is still reserved.

Comment: @SilverWarior. Please read the entire statement, especially this part: "(if the memory is reused)".

Comment: To be more precise, the constructor will also initialize all object fields to 0 - so any previous value is just flushed, even if the pointer is address is re-used.